# How does gdb set software breakpoints in shared library functions?

Tags: debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, breakpoints, internals

I know that [software breakpoints](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdbint_8.html) in an executable file can work through replacing some assembler instruction at the desired place with another one, which cause interrupt. So debugger can stop execution exactly at this place and replace this instruction with original one and ask user about what to do the next or call some commands and etc.

But code of such executable file is not used by another programs and has only one copy in memory. *How can software breakpoints work with a shared libraries?* For instance, how software breakpoints work if I set one at some internal function of C-library (as I understand it has only one copy for all the applications, so we cannot just replace some instruction in it)? Are there any "software breakpoints" techniques for that purpose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer for Linux is that the Linux kernel implements COW (Copy-on-Write): If the code of a shared library is written to, the kernel makes a private duplicate copy of the shared page first, remaps internally virtual memory *just for that process* to the copy, and allows the application to continue. This is completely invisible to userland applications and done entirely in the kernel.

Thus, until the first time a software breakpoint is put into the shared library, its code is indeed *shared*; But *afterwards*, not. The process thereafter operates with a dirty but private copy.

This kernel magic is what allows the debugger to not cause every other application to suddenly stop.

On OSes such as VxWorks, however, this is not possible. From personal experience, when I was implementing a GDB remote debug server for VxWorks, I had to forbid my users from ever single-stepping within `semTake()` and `semGive()` (the OS semaphore functions), since a) GDB uses software breakpoints in its source-level single-step implementation and b) VxWorks uses a semaphore to protect its breakpoints list...

The unpleasant consequence was an interrupt storm in which a breakpoint would cause an interrupt, and within this interrupt there would be another interrupt, and another and another in an unescapable chain resistant even to Ctrl-Z. The only way out was to power off the machine.

Comment: This was VWorks 5 or earlier?

Comment: @osgx It was a heavily customized variant of VxWorks 5.4.